# Flask SQl-Alchemy multiple DB transactions in single request

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a single route Flask web app in which the user submits a URL to the client, some data from the URL is extracted at the server-side and appended to a Postgres DB. Next, further processing is done on the data extracted from the URL and the data entry of the URL in the DB is updated. All this processing is done as background tasks using celery. The work flow looks something like this:

```
@app.route
def app_route(url):
    chain(task1(url) | task2(url))

@celery.task
def task1(url):
   out1 = some_long_task(url)
   append url,out1 to db

@celery.task
def task2(url):
   out2 = some_other_long_task(url)
   update url row in db with out2
```

The reason we do this is that, these two tasks are long tasks, and the user should be able to see the status of the task in the client. Hence, we update the out1 in the DB first so the user can know the status and then with out2 so the user can know the final status. At any point, the user can visit the home page which displays the URLs in the DB currently with their data.

This throws me an error: **psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac**

The url with out1 is appended to the DB correctly without issue. But the second time when we try to update the row we appended in the previous task, it throws the above error. I am guessing flask sqlalchemy only allows a single session to a DB in one request, hence the error. What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error. Switched from flask-sqlalchemy to sqlalchemy to connect to the database since it offers more visibility. One should dispose the engine object by calling engine.dispose() after connecting the app to the database and the error disappears.